# What does "period" mean in this conversation?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

What does the word *period* mean in the following context? It does not seem to be a part of the sentence.

> — Could you please {do something}?
>   — I don't want to do that, **period**.

Comment: Similarly, *..., y punto.* in Spanish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an *intensifier*:

> Grammar. a word, especially an adverb, or other linguistic element that indicates, and usually increases, the degree of emphasis or force to be given to the element it modifies, as very or somewhat; intensive adverb.

In the example, it is equivalent to "at all".

I'd say that a more likely occurrence would be when some form of qualifier was originally specified:

> "You don't want to go to football practice today?"
>
> "I don't want to go to football practice, period."

Comment: Definitely an *intensifier* - more or less meaning *"That's my final word on the subject"*. Probably a more common equivalent (in the UK, at least) is *"end of story"*, often truncated to simply *"End of!"* Particularly favoured by less educated speakers who probably wouldn't know that *period* can mean *a full stop at the end of a sentence*.

Comment: In Irish English, you will sometimes hear the Irish phrase *sin é* ("that's it") used similarly. (Irish phrases are often imported into Irish English.)

Comment: I know someone who, when he wants to make a particularly emphatic statement, will end it with "period, full stop, end of sentence!"

Comment: In your football example, it could also be a reference to the lack of adverb after "football practice" in the reply. The initial question assumes that one might want to go to football practice at *some point in time* (e.g. today), whereas the reply emphasizes that one does not want to go to football practice, *ever*.

Comment: In the UK one might end "Full stop.". which basically means the same thing. It is more common to refer to the punctuation mark `period` (.) as a `full stop`.

Answer (score 24):

In North American English, the `.` at the end of a sentence is called a period.  It ends a sentence; the sentence absolutely cannot continue after the period.  Therefore in conversations, when you say *I will not do this, period*, what you are saying is that you will not do it, and the conversation is over.  You're not going to discuss it anymore, and can't be convinced otherwise; *period*.

Also interesting to note: In British English and some other variants of English the period (`.`) is referred to as a "full stop".  So in those dialects, instead of saying *I will not discuss this, period*, one would say *I will not discuss this, full stop*.  This might be helpful if you're having discussions with someone who speaks another dialect of English.

A more lengthy way to write your example sentence would be:

> I don't want to do this, and that's all I'm going to say on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

*Period* is the punctuation mark used at the end of a sentence (*.*). In that sentence, *period* is used to mean something on the lines of "and I don't want to discuss it," or "end of the story."

Answer (score 1):

It's an interjection, and unlike many interjections, it makes total sense.

What does a period do? It ends a sentence.

The interjection *period*, which is always used at the end of a sentence, means "And that's all there is to say."

It implies finality. There can be no discussion or questioning.

In your example, the speaker *will not* do whatever it is. Don't even try persuading him. Nor does he want to give reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Period simply means "that's all", period.