# What is the common term for the word "menstruation"?

Tags: word-request, terminology

What is the common term for the word "menstruation"?

Can I use [cyclus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyclus)?

In my native language, we normally say it by "monthly guest".

Comment: The word "Period" ?

Comment: @GhaithA - I think that's it, [_period_](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/what-does-period-mean-in-this-conversation). :^)

Comment: I saw once: *someone's on the rag*.

Comment: A) a "cycle" (not "cyclus") describes always the whole repeating time span, in this case from one bleeding to the next. B) if you need something else than "period", describe the register: a euphemism you could use with your elderly aunt? A slang term used by boys talking about girls? .... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstruation / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_taboo#United_States

Answer (score 6):

*Cyclus* isn't a common term.  I never heard that word before this question.

If the context is medical you should use *menstruate*.

*Period* is the common term.  One who is menstruating is said to be *on her period*.  A less direct/somewhat more polite term is *time of the month* - e.g. *It's that time of the month for me ...*, *Is it that time of the month?*

*On the rag* is a (at least AmE) slang term - not vulgar but nowhere near polite.  Often condescending in meaning unless females themselves use the term to express frustration.

Comment: Never heard **on her period** but have heard **having her period**, "she's having her period", "I'm having my period". Have also heard **monthly cycle**, had a Russian friend who called it her **red days**.  Indirectly, having **cramps** may be a sign of menstruation.

Comment: I would consider `on the rag` to be vulgar at best and I'd strongly advise against using it.

Answer (score 1):

The very popular term in India is **"She has MC"** meaning Menstruation cycle.Or, **''the aunt has come!"**

Comment: In France, apparently, it is often called "having the English to stay".

Answer (score 0):

In the UK:
Decoraters in (as in painting) / 
Aunt Flo is visiting / 
On the Blob / 
On / 
On the rag