# Meaning of 'anti-character period'

Tags: word-meaning

Especially, what does 'period' mean? Here is the context:

> Bran is not just the anti-Aragorn, he’s an **anti-character period**.

Here is the link: [‘Game of Thrones’ Ends Not With a Bang but a Whimper](https://www.thedailybeast.com/game-of-thrones-series-finale-the-iron-throne-hbo-epic-ends-not-with-a-bang-but-a-whimper?ref=wrap)

Comment: Punctuation: Bran is not just the anti-Aragorn, he’s an anti-character, period. or he's an anti-character: period.

Answer (score 1):

**Anti-** - opposed to or against a particular thing or person [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anti)

**Period** - said at the end of a statement to show that you believe you have said all there is to say on a subject and you are not going to discuss it any more [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/period)

> He is not just the anti-Aragon, he is opposed to all characters, end of story!

Answer (score 1):

As Bee said, the word *period* verbally emphasizes the punctuation mark, expressing finality or completion.  I'd put a comma before it.

“anti-Aragorn” expresses the contrast between Bran's lack of ambition and Aragorn's long campaign to restore and reclaim the dormant kingship of Gondor and Arnor.

“anti-character” seems to mean that Bran is not as solidly defined as many other characters; he has not been given any clear personality.

(I do not know the story.)

Answer (score 0):

## Two things are happening here: *'anti-'* and *'period'*

This statement insults Bran with two kinds of added emphasis.

- "period" means that the idea has been concluded and there isn't more to add (so the writer is claiming)
- "not just the *anti-*..., an *anti-*..." is a common way of contrasting ideas in English where the second part of the contrast is more extreme, being the claim to stronger truth by the speaker or writer.

Specifically, about the word "period", it needs the comma before it and arguably an exclamation mark after it...

From [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/period):

> American English spoken used to emphasize that you have made a decision and that you do not want to discuss the subject any more, syn. **full stop!**

eg:

> I’m not going, period!

From [Wikipedia, ***Intensifier***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier):

> ...is a linguistic term (but not a proper lexical category) for a modifier that makes no contribution to the propositional meaning of a clause but serves to enhance and give additional emotional context to the word it modifies.

The "intensifier period" has also been discussed on the ELU at length:

- [Origin of “Period” and “Full Stop” as Interjections](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301474/origin-of-period-and-full-stop-as-interjections)
- Answer: "[That is an intensifier](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1066/85693)"