# What can be meant by "night period" in this contex?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have a text and I am not sure about the meaning of "night period" here.

Could it be, that boy says "it's a lovely evening for a walk" and girl answers "yes, it's a beautiful evening"?

> She spotted him walking down the path—right on time.She went to the door, opened it. And liked—what woman
>   wouldn’t—the way he paused, the way he looked at her.
>
> “You’re prompt. I thought I’d head up to the
>   house, save you the walk, but you beat me to it.”
>
> “Nice night for a walk.”
>
> “**Nice night period**. Do you do this often?”
>
> “Do what?”
>
> “Go dancing.”
>
> “Not especially.”

Huge thanks for any help!

Comment: I think she is using _period_ in the American sense of _full stop_. It's a nice night, not just for walking but in general. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/what-does-period-mean-in-this-conversation?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "period" here means the same as "full stop", it is the punctuation that ends a sentence.

Person A says "[It is a] Nice night for a walk."

Person B says "[It is a] Nice night ***.***"  But to emphasise this, B speaks the punctuation

Example:

> — I think a greyhound is good dog for racing.
>   — I think a greyhound is a good dog *period*.  They are friendly and affectionate, they are not only good for speed.

(A British speaker could use the same thing, but say "full stop" instead of "period".)

Your example doesn't mean "length of time"